# How to do SSL mutual authentication in wso2esb with Client and Server

Tags: ssl, wso2, ssl-certificate, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb-4.8.1 with java web client.
I wish to do SSL mutual authentication in wso2esb.My client web as well as android app so i followed **http://pathberiya.blogspot.in/2012/08/enable-mutual-ssl-for-proxy-services-in.html** above blog so i created .jks file and replaced with wso2carbon.jks its working.
But how to do mutual authentication with back end server .It has its own certificate .Can i export that certificate into my wso2esb security folder.In that way  is it work or not.Else i need to use same certificate with back end also help me for this.

client------------>proxy-------------->Backend

getting this error in esb starting level only

```
[ESB] [2014-05-29 18:56:19,653] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Error while updating wso2carbon-sts in STSDeploymentInterceptor {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.KeyStoreUtil.getKeyStoreFileName(KeyStoreUtil.java:57)
```

after that one more error is

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.internal.TenantMgtServiceComponent} -  ******* Tenant Config bundle failed activating **** {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.internal.TenantMgtServiceComponent}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:514
```

This is about the https transport

```
FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Cannot start transports {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Mutual authentication is not currently supported for proxy -> backend communication. See JIRA issue [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2830).

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to enable custom SSL profiles in the axis configuration. For a specific endpoint, you can specify which keystone and which truststore to use. See this post: http://nadeeshaan.blogspot.nl/2014/03/enabling-custom-ssl-in-wso2-esb-4.html